# How do I show text pane of smartart graphic in powerpoint in C#

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint

How do I show text pane of SmartArt graphics in PowerPoint (VSTO addin)?

I can't find any code for text pane, and then only I can show/hide it

```cs
using core = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using pp = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;

public static void CreateOrgChart()
{
    pp.Application app;
    pp.Presentation pres;
    core.SmartArt sa;
    core.SmartArtLayout layout;

    app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
    pres = app.ActivePresentation;

    layout = app.SmartArtLayouts[97]; // 97 - stands for org chart
    sa = pres.Slides[1].Shapes.AddSmartArt(layout).SmartArt;

    //sa.textpane.show(); // does not exists
}
```

[image]
[image]

Also to clarify,
My objective is not to get the Text from the Shape.

Problem is,
Initially when the user clicks that arrow to show the text pane for first time, the text pane is kind of messed up, only when i hide again and reshow again, this gets solved.
[image]

I need to show or hide the text pane for SmartArt in PowerPoint (by code)